# Android ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE - Only owner is able to interact with pending item content

Tags: android, android-camera, video-capture, android-video-record

I'm updating an app to targetSdkVersion 32 from what was originally targetSdkVersion 29. We never got it to the Play Store before November, so I need to update it to >30.

Part of the app is a fairly simple use case - the user can choose to take a picture or record a video and then upload it to our server. I was able to make some adjustments on externalstorage directory and get taking photos working. Video is proving to have more problems.

My dispatch intent is pretty simple:

```
           else if (options[item].equals("Take video"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                    //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                    //intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1); // set video quality
                    // name
                    // start the video capture Intent
                    if (intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
                    }
                }
```

I had to comment out the intent.putExtra lines to get the stock camera app to work properly.

The onActivityResult is also pretty simple. I'm trying to use a MediaMetadataRetriever to validate the length of the video before doing further processing

```
case CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        try {
                            if (data.getData() != null && !data.getData().equals("null")) {
                                Uri videoUri = data.getData();
                                MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
                                retriever.setDataSource(getActivity(), videoUri); //EXCEPTION HERE
                                String time = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
                                long timeInMilliSec = Long.parseLong(time);
                                long duration = timeInMilliSec / 1000;
                                long hours = duration / 3600;
                                long minutes = (duration - hours * 3600) / 60;
                                long seconds = duration - (hours * 3600 + minutes * 60);

                                // less than one minute long videos get sent, otherwise show issue builder
                                if (minutes < 1) {
                                            File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
                                    File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + "PROCESSEDVIDEOS" + "/");
                                    new VideoCompressAsyncTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).execute("false", videoUri.toString(), dir.getPath());
                                } else {
                                    final CharSequence[] options = {"Cancel"};
                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                                    builder.setTitle("You can only send videos less than 60 seconds.");
                                    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                            if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    builder.show();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
```

The app is throwing an `illegalStateException` on the `retriever.setDataSource(getActivity(), videoUri);` line with
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Only owner is able to interact with pending item content://media/external_primary/video/media/25`

I'm presuming there is some asynchronous action going on here, but I can't find any docs on the proper way to know the recorded video is fully available.

Going be simple android docs here: https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics#TaskCaptureIntent

Comment: I have the same problem. Only happens with android emulator api 31.
Tried  targetSdkVersion 30 or 31